# Writing an injectable service in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

The data in my Angular service keeps resetting.
It does not stay cache between two components.

Would anyone know how to solve this.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class PillarService {
  public data: string = null;
}
```

Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/9okaVfVSsRhPxexP9HNw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want a singleton object, so for that do inject service in `bootstrap` function, to make sure its instance get created only once.

```
bootstrap(App, [appRouterProviders, PillarService])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

And then remove it from `providers` array to stop instantiating again.